# Demonstrating that post decrement is not atomic... FAIL

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, linqpad

I was trying out a code sample from [this book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Interlocked) that should demonstrate that the post decrement operator is not atomic. The code is as I have entered it into LinqPad.

```
void Main() {
  var count = 0;
  do {
    _x = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      new Thread(Go).Start();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Try "+ count);
    count++;
  } while (_x == 0);
  Console.WriteLine(_x);
}

int _x = 10000;
void Go() { for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) _x--; }
```

The idea is that decrementing `_x` in parallel on multiple threads without locking may lead to a value of `_x` other then 0 when all the threads have finished.

My problem is that no matter how long I seem to try I always get 0 as a result.
I have run the code on two different computers (both Windows 7) and two different versions of .NET and both give me the same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Increase the iteration count, most likely the threads finish so fast that before you can spin up another, the previous one has ended, never running in parallel. So instead of 100, count to 100000 or something much larger.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes. That was it. I have increased the iteration count in `Go` and I got a non 0 result on the first try. Thank you.

Comment: Create the threads first, then start them in a loop. Or use the Pool. You only need a few, not 1000.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I have tried to create the thread objects outside of the loop but it looks like the cost of starting a thread is still higher then doing the 100 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added 100000 interations in `Go` as Lasse V. Karlsen has suggested. The code now works as expected on the first try. I have also moved the Thread creation out of the loop and reduced the thread count as Henk Holterman has suggested.

```
void Main()
{
    var count = 0;
    do {
    _x = 1000000;
    var threads = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select (_ => new Thread(Go)).ToList();

    foreach (var t in threads)
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Try "+ count);
    count++;
    } while (_x == 0);
    Console.WriteLine(_x);
}

int _x;
void Go() { for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) _x--; }
```

The code now works as expected.